# how the executor interface works in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, threadpoolexecutor

I am studying a book about java sockets, the chapter I just read is about multiple connections, that is, a server that is connected to multiple clients simultaneously via threads. Explain two approaches to creating these connections, 1) create a new thread for each client. 2) use a finite number of N threads to process the requests of N clients simultaneously, and queue the others. Then he introduced the Executor interface, which from what I understand is the best approach because it reuses the threads that we have already used but that we are no longer using (I may have misunderstood since I am reading it in English and I do not understand it well ). So I made an example in java:

```
public class Server{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ServerSocket ServSock=new ServerSocket(6666);
        Executor service=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        while(true){
            Socket ClntSock=ServSock.accept();
            service.execute(new EchoProtocol(ClntSock));
        }
    }
}
```

EchoProtocol.java is a class that extends Thread, the client sends a string to the server and the server sends it the same as the client. To test that it reused threads, I put this in the constructor:

```
System.out.println(getName());
```

But every time I run a new client an ever-increasing index of Thread-0 Thread-1 Thread-2... is printed even if I have finished some clients. So don't reuse threads? What is it that I don't understand?

Comment: From the javadoc of `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`: *Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available.*, and *Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources.*, that may be why you sometimes see new threads, because you waited long enough

Comment: no, every time I start from a new customer I think a new thread is created and not reused one previously because the System.out.println (getName ()); always produces a different thread name, even if one has been terminated for a long time.

Comment: You said that `EchoProtocol extends Thread`, that is probably why, **you** create a new Thread for every new connection. `EchoProtocol` should probably `implements Runnable` and not `extends Thread`

Comment: Now EchoProtocol implements Runnable, and in the run method which was overriding I put: System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); but the output is: pool 1 thread-1    pool 1 thread-2 …. and the same name is never printed twice. If you have any other ideas I would be happy to listen to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve using ExecutorService class